# Show that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $V_k \cap (V_1+\ldots+V_{k-1},V_{k+1}+\ldots+V_n)=\{0\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_1,\ldots,V_n$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Define $V_1+\ldots+V_n$ to be the subspace of $V$ formed by all sums $v_1+\ldots+v_n$ where $v_i \in V_i$.

Show that the map $f:V_1\oplus\ldots \oplus V_n \to V_1 + \ldots V_n$ defined by $f(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=v_1+\ldots + v_n$ is an isomorphism if and only if $V_k \cap (V_1+\ldots+V_{k-1},V_{k+1}+\ldots+V_n)=\{0\}.$

First suppose the map $f$ is an isomorphism and take $v\in V_k \cap (V_1+\ldots+V_{k-1},V_{k+1}+\ldots+V_n)$

This implies that $v=v_1+\ldots + v_{k-1}+v_{k+1}+\ldots+v_n$

I'm stuck at this point though as I'm not sure how to use the fact the $f$ is an isomorphism to conclude that $v=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I would rather write $ f: V_1\times \cdots \times V_n \rightarrow V_1+\cdots+V_n$ (the notation using $\oplus$ indicates already that it's a direct sum, whence an isomorphism).

Anyway, the map is by definition surjective so you need to show it is injective. Suppose it is not. Then there are $(v_1,...,v_n)$ not all zero so that $v_1+\cdots+v_n=0$.

Since not all were zero there is $v_k\neq 0$. But then $v_k = -(v_1 +...+v_{k-1}+v_{k+1}+...+v_n)$ is a non-zero element in the above mentioned intersection.

Conversely if  $v_k = -(v_1 +...+v_{k-1}+v_{k+1}+...+v_n)$ is a non-zero element in the above mentioned intersection then $f(v_1,...,v_k)=0$ so the kernel is non-trivial and the map is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me. However, the converse is not obvious to me. Could you explain this please?